# Square pairs in other bases

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The base nine numbers $17_9=16$ and $71_9=64$ are both squares, while
$14_{12}=16$ and $41_{12}=49$ are both squares.

About a quarter of bases have a pair of two-digit squares that are the reverse of each other, and some bases have several pairs.

I have put the sequence of bases on OEIS at a174525.

How do I calculate the exact proportion of bases that have a pair like that?

Comment: Does the claim that "about a square of bases" apply as a probabilistic limit, or just to small bases that you have considered?

Comment: Also, do you allow the pair $(11_8,11_8)$? $11_8=9$ and both are reverse to each other.

Comment: @CalvinLin, that was up to about 1000.  It looks quite steady at about 25 percent.

Comment: @Tomas, I excluded your example.